# How To Open Camera Using Camera Package in Flutter? (Without ImagePicker)

Tags: flutter, dart, camera

I am building a application for demo. I want to know how we can use camera without using Image Picker. I tried many things but I could not do that. If you experts know so, let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

using this package `camera: ^0.10.0+1`

Answer (score 0):

Follow this official docs to help it will help you how to use the camera package.
https://pub.dev/packages/camera